# How are the transactions going to be verified after all BTC blocks are found?

Tags: transactions, verification

If I understood correctly the current transactions are included in the generation of the next block, thus these transactions get verified.

But what happens when all 21 million bitcoins are already mined? When there is no block to be found anymore? How will then the transactions be verified? Will BTC simply die?

Edit: My question is not about mining decline, my question is how do the future transactions are going to be verified in the case where **all** the blocks are found.

Comment: My question is not about mining decline, my question is how do the future transactions are going to be verified in the case where all the blocks are found.

Comment: There will never be a time when all blocks are found. The subsidy will go down, and eventually reach zero, but there will still be more blocks.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this; I think the real question OP is interested in was answered here already, but not by the duplicate it's linked to.